# Using LINQ to SQL where database tables can have extra columns

Tags: .net, sql, linq, datacontext

Our development team would like to use LINQ to SQL in our data access layer.  An issue we've run into is that the SQL Server database we're accessing can sometimes have additional columns in certain tables.  This variation is limited so that at most we need to account for 5 additional, optional columns.

We realized we could create 5 datacontexts, one for each situation where an optional column is   present, and a switch to utilize the correct one.  But this seemed a bit heavy.

Does anyone know of a way we can continue to use LINQ to SQL, but with some extensibility so that we can use one datacontext instead of 5?

**Note:**  We cannot control the database schema as it is owned by a third party.  Otherwise, we'd always include the extra columns in those tables.

Comment: "Additional" in the sense that, in multiple single-tenant scenarios, sometimes the columns will exist and sometimes they will not exist at all?

Comment: Do these columns ever participate in foreign keys that you would care about in your datacontext?

Comment: L2S isn't going to like that... Simpler option: always have the columns, but with the meaning implementation specific; or: use a blob/clob/extra-table for additional data

Comment: @David, the extra columns are fairly stable.  They may be added to the database when the db is created.  Once there, they never go away.

Comment: @jklemmack, yes they relate to other tables but we could nix the foreign key relationships in favor of an extensible datacontext

Comment: @MarcGravell, can you expound a bit?  I'm uncertain what you mean by having the meaning implementation specific.  Also, we cannot control the database schema as it is owned by a third party.

Comment: @Lane meaning; the columns names/existence doesn't change - but instead the software decides what it *means*. Still pretty horribly

Answer (score 0):

Our development team decided this wasn't going to work very well with LINQ.  So we used ADO.NET SqlCommands instead, writing our own SQL instead of having LINQ generate it.  This allowed us the flexibility of changing the SQL when the extra columns were present while retaining a single data layer class instead of five.